# Bitcoin transaction query

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-wallet-app

I sent a bitcoin for exchange of etherium from blockchain
But not received anything from the buyer for the past 48 hours.
I am attaching the screenshot of two transactions where the second one is transfer from the my old btc to new btc account showing in green.

The next one is transfer from my new btc to seller account showing in red 
see the vallets 
1HZCArUVZJCKKwmRVQWh78v3vHZJ2bGPcY   is having nil balance
3HuQXaxerUujQw5kDbSyQLGERVTNvTBnn    is having balance of 0.0049

Is it possible to recover my money ?  Please advise[image]

Comment: Hi,  I have not given the BTC address to seller.  I have given only etherium address to the seller.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it possible to recover my money?**

No, Bitcoin transactions are irreversible.

You could try to contact the other party and either ask about the delay or request a refund.

If you believe the other party is committing a fraud, you can report the problem to your local police - but for small amounts it is unlikely that any action can be taken.

Answer (score 0):

How you can expect Ethereum being sent on your BTC address?
The simplest method is to transfer BTC to some exchange (Poloniex, Bitrix ... ) and exchange your assets there.
I am afraid you may not get your money back.

Comment: 0x0ebD1477697E086255992fAa2e530e42EcC20fd7    is my eth address